# How do you charge soul gems?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [How do Soul Gems work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/how-do-soul-gems-work)

I've looted a bunch of soul gems. However, they are currently quite worthless. How do I get them charged up so that I can actually use them?

Answer (score 1):

You need the soul trap spell to charge them. You can sometimes find items that are enchanted with it or you can buy it from a wizard as a tome so you can learn it yourself.

Comment: You can also buy filled gems.